# Create a coordinate map using c++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, c++11

[image]

Can you tell me how to do this kind using normall c++ codes.
I dont need the coloring only the maping .
Must i use a 2D array?
if i use array then how to mark certain points diffently?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw coordinates in ncurses c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768544/how-to-draw-coordinates-in-ncurses-c)

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't think it's curses

Comment: *"Can you tell me how to do this kind"* - What kind? *"I dont need the coloring only the maping"* - What mapping? What is the actual question you are asking?

Comment: Earier i used ncurses to achive it but i was not able to mark certain codinates differently. so i let go the ncurses idea and want to know is it possible to be done via normal c++ codes

Comment: @ChristianRau I need to know how to draw a similar version using c++ copies without any concern to the colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code gets the job done And it is very simple!

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void draw(int,int);
int main()
{
    cout<<"Main Board\n";
    draw(3,4);

    system("pause");
}

void draw(int x, int y)
{
    for(int i = -6; i < 7; i++)
        if (i < 0)
            cout<<" "<<i;
        else
            cout<<"  "<<i;
    cout<<endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            cout<<(char)(i + 49);
            for(int j = -6; j < 7; j++)
            if(i == y - 1 && j == x)
                cout<<" x ";
            else
                cout<<" . ";

            cout<<(char)(i + 49)<<endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi user, you got what i wantedm but i cant modify to mark certain points differently. say the point (2,3) needs to be different

Comment: Thanks alot, very close to what i wanted, but i think i did not explain myself properly and its my bet.. verry sorry

Comment: The values given to the user is a array of int say Xaxis[]={2,4,5}
Yaxis[]={1,2,3} and if i use a loop the data is not marked or get mixed up. How can i achieve it please advice

Comment: I modified the codes to use arrays but the y axis in not getting printed at the correct position. It always print 1 position lesser. do have a look at the edit. thanks